# Oracle 11g doesn't show Pound symbol when fetched

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g as my database. I am updating the table as below:

```
UPDATE Discount_table SET discount_text='Minimum Commitment Charge - £500 - Discount' WHERE description_code=12345;
```

But the result in database is coming as below:

> Minimum Commitment Charge - ¿500 - Discount

I tried giving nvarchar datatype for it. But its the same result. What needs to be done?

Comment: is your database utf-8 ?

Comment: Looks like you can set charsets on oracle databases. This looks like a likely link:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch2charset.htm

Comment: It is  the difference between your `locale-specific character set` and `database character set`. See [Why are junk values/special characters/question marks displayed on my client?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/)

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly due to the mismatch between the locale-specific NLS characterset and the database characterset. Or else, the `NLS_LANG` value is not correctly set in the OS environmental variable.

Follow steps described here [Why are junk values/special characters/question marks displayed on my client?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/)

**Check the locale-specific NLS characterset :**

```
select value from v$nls_parameters 
  where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

**Check the database characterset :**

```
select value from nls_database_parameters 
  where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

If you see a mismatch between the two, then set the locale-specific NLS characterset to that of database characterset.

If the above charactersets match, then you need to set the `NLS_LANG` value in the OS environmental variable.

For Windows OS, the format is `[NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]`

Follow the instruction in the documentation regarding setting up the NLS_LANG : [Setting the NLS_LANG Environment Variable for Oracle Databases](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can chenge your update stetment like

```
UPDATE Discount_table SET discount_text='Minimum Commitment Charge - '||chr(163)||'500 - Discount' WHERE description_code=12345;
```

I think this will help you to get the pound symbol

Comment: After putting chr(163),it is coming as Â£500 - Discount in unix box.Any idea what is this error?